# Charting API for Asp.net MVC 3 & Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, charts

I am looking for a good, free charting api that looks visually appealing and has lots of charts to choose from.

I am using asp.net mvc 3 and jquery so I am intending to use ajax.

I been looking at some of the posts on stack here about mvc and the MS charting control but I am still unclear if it works well with ajax or if your like using a webform page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use flot or jqplot.

This site has more info:

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts). Its purely JavaScript based and highly integrated with `jQuery`.

http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts

Comment: Looks nice but I am looking for a free product(for commercial use)

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this post yet? http://www.codecapers.com/post/Build-a-Dashboard-With-Microsoft-Chart-Controls.aspx

It has a great example of integrating the ASP.NET Charting library into your MVC app.

**Option 2**: [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery.html)

Comment: Where do I get the .dll I need?

Comment: Also do I need to use view state(ie webform stuff) with it?

Comment: This is the same one right? http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/07/built-in-charting-controls-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx

Comment: From the ScottGu blog you're linking, there's a link at the bottom ' how to use the ASP.NET Chart control within an ASP.NET MVC application' that takes you to the link I provided with specific info for MVC integration.

Comment: Ya, I saw that later on. It seems like it needs to use asp.net controls(I am trying to stay away from webform controls).

Answer (score 0):

There are currently five available on [jQuery List](http://jquerylist.com/category/charts_and_presentations) that you may find useful.